# If I use a for loop with a string, will it check character by character?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I don't particularly care about what happens at the end at this point. I'm merely trying to understand Python's behavior with string inputs more intimately by asking this question.

Specifically, I'd like to know what using a for loop applied to a string will do in this example. Does it look for the whole string and consider the loop over after it checks for the whole string, or will it look for each character in the string individually (or neither of these things and if neither, what?)?

```
def some_procedure(sentence,characters):
    for character in characters:
        if character in sentence:
            do something

print some_procedure('This is a test','iae')
```

I want the code to cycle through every character in a given string and look at another string to see if any of those characters are present, then do something else that I will introduce once I understand how this part of the code works. To be specific to my example above, I want to cycle through all characters ('i', 'a', 'e) in the string `characters` and if a character is in `sentence`, do something to it in `sentence` (eventually).

I understand that I may need to introduce a `.find` at some point and that the code isn't complete, but please humor me. I'm a beginner, so I'm still just trying to understand what reason I would even want to write code like the above for strings. To do that, I need to understand how the for loop interacts with a strings and play with it a bit. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try iterating over a string with, say, a `print` statement in the body of the loop?

Comment: I agree with @kindall, this is definitely an example of something that you could have easily tried on your own and figured out.

Comment: @NateMara I read this more as a question of someone trying to reason over code (what's happening internally) vs an exercise in dynamic programming.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, that is correct. Thank you for explaining it to the others. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). It's one of the coolest things in programming!

Did you ever wonder why they call it a *string*? Because it's a *string of characters*. If you're picturing a bunch of letters on an actual string or piece of yarn in your mind, **good!**

Like many things in Python, strings are **iterable**. That means we can treat them like `lists`. After all, in a way, they *are* lists: lists of characters.

In practice, this means we can loop over them:

```
>>> for letter in 'hello':
...   print(letter)
...
h
e
l
l
o
```

We can take **slices** of them:

```
>>> 'hello'[:2]
'he'
>>> 'hello'[3:]
'lo'
>>> 'hello'[2:4]
'll'
```

We can even **index** them!

```
>>> 'hello'[0]
'h'
```

So now what do you think happens when we pass them to a `for` loop?

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you taking the time to answer. That's exactly what I needed to know, in the first part. Didn't think to do that. Had complex-itis since the stuff I was learning was way more complicated. I'm such an amateur, lol. Adapting to online learning is tough! Am used to working from a book where I can just flip back through, skim read, and remind myself by re-reading "that place where x was taught". Now I have to filter through 100 videos to try to find the right one that teaches the concept I want to review! Anyway, thanks dude! If I could upvote, I would!

Comment: No worries, mate. If you ever want to take the plunge on a new (but difficult at first) language that will really force you to internalize polymorphism, try out Haskell. ;)